# Why are records not showing up on preview page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

We are using Repeater control to dynamically add sections to control.

Each section contains several columns.

A user enters information on one section and if needed, clicks to add another section for additional information.

We are using multiview control for this.

View1 for user data entry.
View2 is to preview data and if everything looks good, submits records.

This works great.

The issue that I am having is presenting preview page for users to review the information they had entered.

Initially, we were able to preview whatever records were entered.

Since yesterday, when we added a few more form fields, suddenly, when you click the preview page, it comes up blank.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Sorry, long code. I posted what I thought was relevant code.

```
   private void SetRowData2()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox tbaircity = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("aircraftCity");
                    TextBox tbaircnty = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("aircraftcnty");
                    DropDownList tbairstate = (DropDownList)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("aircraftstate");
                    TextBox tbTextBox2 = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("aRegNo");
                    TextBox tbTextBox3 = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("aMake");
                    TextBox tbTextBox4 = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("aModelNo");
                    TextBox tbTextBox5 = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("aYRBuilt");
                    TextBox tbTextBox6 = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("aSN");
                    TextBox tbdatePurchased = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("txtdatePurchased");
                    RadioButtonList tbPurchaseType = (RadioButtonList)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("rblPurchaseType");
                    TextBox tbPrevOnwerName = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("txtPrevOnwerName");
                    TextBox tbprevAddr = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("txtprevAddr");
                    TextBox tbprevCity = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("txtprevCity");
                    DropDownList tbPrevState = (DropDownList)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("ddlPrevState");
                    TextBox tbprevzip = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("txtprevzip");
                    TextBox tbbuyername = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("txtbuyername");
                    TextBox tbbuyeraddress = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("txtbuyeraddress");
                    TextBox tbbuyercity = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("txtbuyercity");
                    DropDownList tbbuyerstate = (DropDownList)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("lblbuyerstate");
                    TextBox tbbuyerzip = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("txtbuyerzip");
                    TextBox tbdatesold = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("txtdatesold");
                    TextBox tbsalePrice = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("txtsalePrice");
                    TextBox tbdescription = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("txtDescription");
                    TextBox tbTextBox9 = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("aircraftCost");
                    TextBox tbBtwnTBO = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("hrsBtwnTBO");
                    TextBox tbOverhaul = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("hrsOverhaul");
                    RadioButtonList tbrbllastOverHaul = (RadioButtonList)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("rbllastOverHaul");
                    TextBox tbTotalOnAirFrm = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("TotOnAirFrm");
                    TextBox tbAvionics = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("txtavionics");
                    RadioButtonList tbissues = (RadioButtonList)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("rblIssues");
                    TextBox tbissuedetails = (TextBox)Repeater2.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("functionalIsses");
                    drCurrentRow = dt.NewRow();

                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["aircity"] = tbaircity.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["aircnty"] = tbaircnty.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["airstate"] = tbairstate.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["aRegNo"] = tbTextBox2.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["Make"] = tbTextBox3.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["ModelNo"] = tbTextBox4.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["YRBuilt"] = tbTextBox5.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["SN"] = tbTextBox6.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["txtdatePurchased"] = tbdatePurchased.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["rblPurchaseType"] = tbPurchaseType.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["rblPurchaseType"] = tbPurchaseType.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["PrevOnwerName"] = tbPrevOnwerName.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["prevAddr"] = tbprevAddr.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["prevCity"] = tbprevCity.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["PrevState"] = tbPrevState.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["prevzip"] = tbprevzip.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["buyername"] = tbprevzip.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["buyeraddress"] = tbprevzip.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["buyercity"] = tbprevzip.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["buyerstate"] = tbprevzip.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["buyerzip"] = tbprevzip.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["datesold"] = tbprevzip.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["salePrice"] = tbprevzip.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["description"] = tbprevzip.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["aCost"] = tbTextBox9.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["BtwnTBO"] = tbBtwnTBO.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["Overhaul"] = tbOverhaul.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["rbllastOverHaul"] = tbrbllastOverHaul.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["TotalOnAirFrm"] = tbBtwnTBO.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["Avionics"] = tbAvionics.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["rissues"] = tbAvionics.Text;
                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["issuedetails"] = tbAvionics.Text;

                    rowIndex += 1;
                }
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }
    }

//preview of data

    private void FillSummary()
    {

         SetRowData2();

        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            ////Initialize datatable.
            DataTable ctable = ViewState["CurrentTable"] as DataTable;

            ////Lets start looping through the second datatable for aircraft schedule info. .
            if (ctable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in ctable.Rows)
                {
                    //Aircraft schedule
                    string acity = row.ItemArray[1] as string;
                    string acnty = row.ItemArray[2] as string;
                    string arstate = row.ItemArray[3] as string;
                    string Regno = row.ItemArray[4] as string;
                    string mfgmake = row.ItemArray[5] as string;
                    string mfgmodel = row.ItemArray[6] as string;
                    string yrbuilt = row.ItemArray[7] as string;
                    string sn = row.ItemArray[8] as string;
                    string dtepurchased = row.ItemArray[9] as string;
                    string rbPurchaseType = row.ItemArray[10] as string;

                    //Previous Onwer info
                    string PrevOnwerName = row.ItemArray[11] as string;
                    string prevAddr = row.ItemArray[12] as string;
                    string prevCity = row.ItemArray[13] as string;
                    string PrevState = row.ItemArray[14] as string;
                    string prevzip = row.ItemArray[15] as string;

                    //New buyer info
                    string buyername = row.ItemArray[16] as string;
                    string buyeraddress = row.ItemArray[17] as string;
                    string buyercity = row.ItemArray[18] as string;
                    string buyerstate = row.ItemArray[19] as string;
                    string buyerzip = row.ItemArray[20] as string;
                    string datesold = row.ItemArray[21] as string;
                    string salePrice = row.ItemArray[22] as string;
                    string decription = row.ItemArray[23] as string;

                    string cost = row.ItemArray[24] as string;
                    string hrsbtwn = row.ItemArray[25] as string;
                    string hrsSince = row.ItemArray[26] as string;
                    string LOverhaul = row.ItemArray[27] as string;
                    string totHrs = row.ItemArray[28] as string;
                    string avionics = row.ItemArray[29] as string;
                    string rissues = row.ItemArray[30] as string;
                    string issuedetails = row.ItemArray[31] as string;

                    //Preparing to preview user entries 
                    lblAircraftCity.Text += acity + "<br />";
                    lblAircraftcnty.Text += acnty + "<br />";
                    lAblircraftstate.Text += arstate + "<br />";
                    lblARegNo.Text += Regno + "<br />";
                    lblAMake.Text += mfgmake + "<br />";
                    lblAModelNo.Text += mfgmodel + "<br />";
                    lblAYRBuilt.Text += yrbuilt + "<br />";
                    lblASN.Text += sn + "<br />";
                    lblDatePurchased.Text += dtepurchased + "<br />";
                    if (rbPurchaseType != null)
                    { 
                        lblPurchType.Text += rbPurchaseType + "<br />";
                    }
                    lblFNamePrev.Text += PrevOnwerName + "<br />"; 
                    lblAddrPrev.Text += prevAddr + "<br />"; 
                    lblCityPrev.Text += prevCity + "<br />";
                    lblZipPrev.Text += prevzip + "<br />";
                    lblPurchOnwer.Text += buyername + "<br />";

                    lblPurchOnwer.Text += buyername + "<br />";
                    lblPurcAddr.Text += buyeraddress + "<br />";
                    lblPurcCity.Text += buyercity + "<br />";
                    Label1.Text += buyerstate + "<br />";
                    lblPurcZip.Text += buyerzip + "<br />";
                    lblDdatesold.Text += datesold + "<br />";
                    lblSalePrice.Text += salePrice + "<br />";
                    lblDescription.Text += decription + "<br />";
                    Label3.Text += rissues + "<br />";
                    lblfunctionalIsses.Text += issuedetails + "<br />";

                    lblAircraftCost.Text += cost + "<br />";
                    lblHrsBtwnTBO.Text += hrsbtwn + "<br />";
                    lblHrsOverhaul.Text += hrsSince + "<br />";
                    if (LOverhaul != null)
                    {
                        lblOverhaul.Text += LOverhaul + "<br />";
                    }
                        lblTotOnAirFrm.Text += totHrs + "<br />";
                    lblavionics.Text += avionics + "<br />";
                    if (rissues != null)
                    {
                        lblsitus.Text += rissues + "<br />";
                    }
                    lblfunctionalIsses.Text += issuedetails + "<br />";
                    rowIndex += 1;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: @mason,

They are showing blank when I use the debugger. I already know that but any ideas why they are showing blank?